# clean code vs bunch of temp tables

Tags: sql-server

```
TableA -- list of objects
--------
Rec1
Rec2
Rec3

TableB  -- list of TONS of details A->B = 1->MMM
--------
Rec1, data..., String1
Rec1, data..., String1
Rec1, data..., String1
Rec1, data..., String2
Rec2, data..., String1
Rec2, data..., String1
Rec3, data..., String1
Rec3, data..., String1
Rec3, data..., String2
Rec3, data..., String2
Rec3, data..., String3
```

A query reduces Table B to a much smaller number of records by cutting some details, leaving a 1->M

```
QueryResult
------------
Rec1, String1
Rec1, String2
Rec2, String1
Rec3, String1
Rec3, String2
Rec3, String3
```

Trying to build

```
Final
---------
Rec1, String1 + String2
Rec2, String1
Rec3, String1 + String2 + String3
```

I tried adding columns for each distinct String, packing the strings in appropriately and then concatenating the individual strings into a summary column.  While this works, it looks ugly and is reminiscent of only having a hammer in my toolbox.

Is there a more elegant solution utilizing tools other than my big ole hammer?

Comments and insights would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please be more precise in what you are trying to accomplish and what you have done.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in tonythewest.  iamdave nailed it in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `for xml`, joining your original `TableA` to your `QueryResult`:

```
declare @TableA table(TableA nvarchar(10));
insert into @TableA values('Rec1'),('Rec2'),('Rec3');

declare @QueryResult table(TableA nvarchar(10),TableB nvarchar(10));
insert into @QueryResult values('Rec1','String1'),('Rec1','String2'),('Rec2','String1'),('Rec3','String1'),('Rec3','String2'),('Rec3','String3');


select TableA
        ,stuff((select ', ' + TableB  -- The ', ' is the delimiter.  The first instance of this is removed by the STUFF function.
                from @QueryResult t2
                where t1.TableA = t2.TableA
                order by t2.TableB
                for xml path('')
               )
              ,1,2,''                 -- This is where you specify how much from the start to remove.  
              ) as TableB
from @TableA t1;
```

Output:

```
+--------+---------------------------+
| TableA |          TableB           |
+--------+---------------------------+
| Rec1   | String1, String2          |
| Rec2   | String1                   |
| Rec3   | String1, String2, String3 |
+--------+---------------------------+
```

The `stuff` function starts at the nth character as specified in your first parameter value (in this case `1`) and replaces it and everything up to the character in the second parameter position (in this case character `2`) with your third parameter value (in this case an empty string `''`).

This means that the normal out put of the `for xml` statement above would be `, String1, String2` for `Rec1`, but after the `stuff` is applied the first two characters are replaced with an empty string, so `String`, String2` results.

Comment: You've beaten me by seconds :-) +1

Comment: Pull your finger out Shnugs

Comment: @iamdave Thank you.  Searched for ages for previous questions, posted this and thennn found long discussions on this topic.  Appreciate your short and sweet solution.